# Angular SlickGrid align header text

Tags: css, angular, slickgrid

I am using Angular `SlickGrid` and want to center or right-align the text in the column headers. Not all columns the same way.

I figured out, there is a `headerCssClass` property in the column definition, but all the way I tried, this style never seems to get applied.

For the column-definition:

```
    {
        id: 'sourceNumber',
        name: 'SourceNumber',
        field: 'SourceNumber',
        sortable: true,
        width: 150,
        headerCssClass: 'text-right',
        cssClass: 'text-right'
    },
```

In the CSS file:

```
    .text-right {
        text-align: right;
    }
```

It works fine for the cell contents. But the text in the header is still left align.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For aligning grid cell, I typically use the Formatters that I created for that purpose `alignCenter` and `alignRight` (see all Formatters in the [Formatters - Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Formatters#list-of-provided-formatters)), you could also use the extra CSS class like you did.

If you keep the extra CSS class, then there's an extra `float: left` on the `.slick-column-name` class that you will probably have to cancel out and that is probably what is blocking (or cancelling) your CSS. However I must say, it's on the left for a reason, it's not ideal to move it to a different position (especially on the right) because you might conflict with the header menu & sort icons (you will for sure if you align right)

```css
.slick-column-name {
  float: none;
}
```

Also note that the column definition `name` property also accepts HTML code (it might not be documented though), but even then you will probably have to cancel the float first

```js
this.columnDefinitions = [
  { id: 'firstName', field: 'firstName', name: '<span style="color: blue">First Name</span>' },
];
```

Lastly, you should also take a look at all the SASS variables (which also have CSS variable equivalent names), you can see all the variables in this [_variables](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/master/packages/common/src/styles/_variables.scss) file, there's a lot of variables available but it doesn't seem to include any for the header alignment (we can add variables for that in the future), there's also this [CSS Styling - Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Styling) that has info in that regard.

Please note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid

Comment: Hi ghiscoding! Thanks for the developing and maintaining Angular-Slickgrid. And thank you for your answer. Pushed me in the right direction. 
Canceled the float in the CSS-class. Now all column headers are centered. But with html inside the name property I can change float to 'left' or 'right', which is exactly what I needed :-)

Comment: glad to see that helps, if that answers the question you can upvote the answer and maybe the lib too ;-)

Comment: I did upvote the answer, but unfortunately my reputation is still too low. But it has been recorded. That's what Stackoverflow tells me ;-)
Where can I upvote the lib?

Comment: I upvoted your question, it might give you enough points to upvote & accept my answer, as for upvoting my lib that would be to give a star on GitHub and you need an account on GitHub for that. happy holidays

Comment: My reputation is still not enough, but I hope it will be soon and then it should be counted. Upvoted your lib on GitHub as well.
If you find some time, I have another question concerning the row height:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70424298/angular-slickgrid-row-height-maybe-also-margin-or-padding
Happy holiday, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have sorting turned on, then the issue would be the float attribute of the slick-column-name/slick-sort-indicator. It prevents the alignment.

add the following to styles.scss

`.slick-column-name { float: none; }`

Comment: why post the same answer that I wrote a year ago?